# Proteus design buzzer quiz circuit

Tags: led, switches, proteus, buzzer

I am trying to design a 12-people buzzer quiz game.

I just want to use LEDs and AND and NOT gates, using one switch for reset.

The problem is that after designing it all the odd LEDs or even LEDs would turn on together after pushing the buttons one by one, and I have no idea how to reset all the LEDs together.

Can someone give me some help with this?

[image]

Comment: Your schematic is hard to read, but I think there are 6 independet RS flipflops with wrong connected input switches (no GND) and missing series resistors for the LEDs. How will you make a 12 user buzzer game out of this? What is the intended function?

Comment: What you are designing is called a "game show circuit".  To get the general idea, there are lotsa schematics for this on the innergoogle.  Most of them have one thing in common:  one set-reset or D flipflop *per user*.  So to start, you need 12 more AND gates plus inverters.  Consider adding signal diodes and resistors to your allowed comoponents list.  Without them, you will need a *ton* of AND gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- each user needs an edge-triggered latch but only the first can trigger all latches, by the leading edge.  The clock can be used with a suitable x-second timer to trigger a momentary reset automatically.  LEDs and buzzers can be driven from the active low open drain driver to Vdd.

A quick and dirty concept is shown below. But warning these gates are rarely used and thus expensive.

[image]

- replicate all the common traces like the 1st.